# Find untranslated keys in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

Is there really no way to extract all i18n translation keys of an application?

*views/pages/index.html.erb*

```
<h1>Some content</h1>
<p><%= t('.some_translated_text') %></p>
```

*views/pages/show.html.erb*

```
<p><%= t('.some_other_stuff') %></p>
```

It would be great to have a tool that runs over the application and extracts all keys e.g.:

```
generic:
  views:
    pages:
      index:
        some_translated_text: "missing"
      show:
        some_other_stuff: "missing"
```

I really can't believe nobody has written such an extraction tool until now...

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

I know this [i18n-missing_translations](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-missing_translations) but hope there is an easier way.

Comment: As a point of clarification, you're talking about extracting the text from the view, right?

Comment: @BryanH I would like to translate the translation keys from the views.

Comment: To extract all keys, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011410/extract-i18n-translation-keys-from-rails-project

Comment: @mccannf Thanks for the hint. I will have a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appear to be a number of possible approaches to this.

1. Create a script (e.g. with `awk` or `sed`) to scan your files with the regular expression in this question:
   [Extract I18n translation keys from rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011410/extract-i18n-translation-keys-from-rails-project)
2. Use a Rails plugin like the following: https://github.com/romanbsd/translate.

   You can run `rake translate:missing` and it will identify the missing keys.
3. Incorporate tests for missing keys into your test suite framework, assuming your framework covers all views. 
   See http://dev.innovationfactory.nl/2009/05/04/rails-i18n-caveats-and-tips/#translations